# Getting a node value depending on an another value at the same level

Tags: xpath

For each "item" node in the following XML structure, I want to select the corresponding "title" (the text nodes are located at the same level as the item nodes, I can't modify it).

The link between those two nodes will be the "ref" node which is a kind of primary key between the "item" and "title" trees.

Is it possible in XPath ?

I think it should be something like this: //root/item/../title[ref/text()=??????]/label

An example :

```
<root>
    <item>
        <ref>ITEM001</ref>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ref>ITEM002</ref>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ref>ITEM003</ref>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ref>ITEM004</ref>
    </item>
    <title>
        <ref>ITEM002</ref>
        <label>Hello world!</label>
    </title>
    <title>
        <ref>ITEM003</ref>
        <label>Goodbye world!</label>
    </title>
    <title>
        <ref>ITEM007</ref>
        <label>This is a test!</label>
    </title>
    <title>
        <ref>ITEM0010</ref>
        <label>No this a question!</label>
    </title>
</root>
```

The result would be:

- ITEM001: empty
- ITEM002: Hello world!
- ITEM003: Goodbye world!
- ITEM004: empty

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume if you follow below steps you would get you desired output.
 Step 1: Iterate through all the Items tag and capture all in an array.
 Step 2: Using a loop on array use the below XPath to find the respective label value.
         //title[contains(.,'')]/label.
 Step 3: If you find an matching element then get the text of the label to display on console else display empty.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, I'm looking for a solution only in XPath. So, it's not possible to iterate on nodes.